# Multiple user emails for multiple tag additions

Tags: clojure, datomic, data-retrieval

In the system, a user can add a tag to an extant entry like the following:

```
(defn add-tag-to-post [eid email tags]
  (let [cast-eid (Long. eid)]
       (d/transact conn [{:db/id cast-eid,
                          :author/email email,
                          :post/tag tags}])))
```

Which, I think, should drop in a transaction that has the email and the tags added with the entity id.

---

I want to be able to query over all the changes on this data and see **which user email added which tag.**  Currently, when a user adds a new tag, all the email fields reflect the most recent user's email:

```
(defn get-all-post-history-by-eid [eid]
   (->> (d/q '[:find ?title ?content ?tags ?email ?eid
               :in $ ?eid
               :where
              [?eid post/title ?title]
              [?eid post/content ?content]
              [?eid author/email ?email]
              [?eid post/tag ?tags]] (d/db conn) eid)
         (map (fn [[title content tags email eid]]
              {:title title
               :content content
               :tags tags
               :email email
               :eid eid}))
         (sort-by :email)))
```

returns

```
({:title "Straight edges...", 
  :content "If ...", 
  :tags "art",                        <diff tag
  :email "randomlady@mailnator.hax",  <same email
  :eid 1759} 
 {:title "Straight edges ....", 
  :content "If ... ", 
  :tags "scissor-less edges",         <diff tag
  :email "randomlady@mailnator.hax",  < same email
  :eid 1759} 
 {:title "Straight edges ...", 
  :content "If ...", 
  :tags "paper",                      <diff tag
  :email "randomlady@mailnator.hax",  < same email
  :eid 1759} ... )
```

point being: all the different tags were added by different emails, but querying simply returns the same email in all the fields (the most recent email to add a tag to the entity)

I just changed the ordinality of my author/email attribute in the schema.edn to be "many" instead of one, thinking that might have something to do with it.  But that's not it.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks =)

---

Edit: I'm thinking maybe I need a tag/author field like:

```
  post/tag      }
  author/email  } nothing tying these two together

+ tag/author    } does it make sense to add this?  will try and get back.
```

---

Edit#2: SO, I think I made a breakthrough (cognitively) with the help of the words on this page 
http://tonsky.me/blog/unofficial-guide-to-datomic-internals/

Basically, Datomic respects the *entity* which means that if you change an entity attribute (well, when you record a new value for an attribute, no changing/deletion happens) then you are effectively asking for the most recent values of that attribute.

Meaning that for each tag that's added, it would be proper to make a new entity, and in that entity it can have a reference to the post that it modulates.

So from something that looked like

```
EID  Attribute      Value     "Time/Transaction ID"
 37  :post/title     "Bees"           7
 37  :author/email   "v@a.x"          7
 37  :post/tag       "hive"           7
 37  :author/email   "diana@p"        8
 37  :post/tag       "mind"           8
```

If you change the attribute :post/tag even with a new :author/email, you are still modifying the entity with ID 37, which will effectively "overwrite" those values (well, tag is ordinality/many so that one is additive, but email will 'overwrite')

My *desired* behavior is more like

```
EID  Attribute      Value     "Time/Transaction ID"
 37  :post/title     "Bees"           7
 37  :author/email   "v@a.x"          7


 38  :post/tag       "honeycomb"      8
 38  :author/email   "squire@o"       8
 38  :tag/post (ref)   37             8
```

Meaning, the entity with ID 38 has all new values, and successfully points-to / refers to entity 37.

Writing out questions helps a lot!  Once I get the implementation down I'll try and update this question.  Hope this helps someone in case they need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works!

```
(defn get-all-post-history-by-eid [pid]
  (->> (d/q '[:find ?title ?content ?tags ?email ?pid
              :in $ ?pid
              :where
              [?pid post/title ?title]
              [?pid post/content ?content]
              [?tid tag/post ?pid]         <new schema stuff
              [?tid tag/value ?tags]       <means new way to see the world
              [?tid author/email ?email]] (d/db conn) pid)
       (map (fn [[title content tags email pid]]
              {:title title
               :content content
               :tags tags
               :email email
               :eid pid}))
       (sort-by :email)))
```

As you can see, there are new fields in the query, namely:

```
tag/post
tag/value
```

tag/post has the valueType of ref in the schema,
tag/value has cardinality/many and is a String.

This way, the tagging and the posts are decoupled.  Now, when I query to get all the history of a post with something like

```
vhax.dbmethods>  (get-all-post-history-by-eid 1759)
```

The result is like

```
({:title "Straight edges without scissors", 
  :content "If you ever ... ", 
  :tags "skizzorz", 
  :email "so.ku@mail.hax", :bid 1759} 

 {:title "Straight edges without scissors", 
  :content "If you ever ...  ", 
  :tags "snips", 
  :email "vild@hax.pong", :bid 1759})
```

reflecting the tag that was added by whatever email.  Success.  Really feel like Datomic clicked for me today.